# Can you use custom keywords with ETW

Tags: etw

Is it possible to use custom keywords with ETW?

I'm using ETW for logging/tracing/diagnostics in my application and I'd like the ability to assign keywords for easier querying of the logs. Diagnostics, Timed Event, Information, and others that are more specific such as DB Connection or whatever.

Comment: Can you please explain question a little more?

Comment: I added some additional info on why I would like to use custom keywords

Comment: Please supply the platform. Is this for a .NET application? ETW is used very differently from different languages.

Comment: Sorry about that. This is for .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible when you use the [EventSource Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource):

```
public class Keywords   // This is a bitvector
{
    public const EventKeywords Requests = (EventKeywords)0x0001;
    public const EventKeywords Debug = (EventKeywords)0x0002;
}
```

This is also explained in the `_EventSourceUsersGuide.docx` which you can find in your solution after adding the NuGet package.